# A question about complex using geometric.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_{1}$, $z_{2}$, and $z_{3}$ be three distinct complex numbers. Prove that these numbers are collinear if and only if the quotient $(z_{3}-z_{1})$ \ $(z_{2}-z_{1})$ is a real number.
 I have been working on this problem but everything i tried it is not working or even making sense . If anyone can help that would be great. By the way should i kept on trying to find the real part of the quotient.

Comment: If and only if *what* about the quotient?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If $z_1, z_2, z_3$ are on the same line, then $z_n = z + t_ne^{i\theta}$ for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $t_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_2-z_1}$ is real, then $z_3 = z_1 + t(z_2-z_1)$ for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.